# schema validation HELP (converted from Biztalk 2004 to 2006 R2)

Tags: validation, xsd, biztalk

This schema used to work on our Biztalk 2004 environment but throws an error when compiled in Biztalk 2006 R2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://Project.Schemas.External.ScheduleRepair" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="schedulerepair">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
        <xs:extension base="xs:anyType">
          <xs:sequence>           
            <xs:element name="customerremarks">
              <xs:complexType />
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

now we get this error:

> Error 54 Wildcard '##any' allows
>   element 'customerremarks', and causes
>   the content model to become ambiguous.
>   A content model must be formed such
>   that during validation of an element
>   information item sequence, the
>   particle contained directly,
>   indirectly or implicitly therein with
>   which to attempt to validate each item
>   in the sequence in turn can be
>   uniquely determined without examining
>   the content or attributes of that
>   item, and without any information
>   about the items in the remainder of
>   the
>   sequence. C:\Project\ScheduleRepair.xsd

I don't see anything different about the mentioned node. Besides when i delete that node, it'll just go on to point out something else as the culprit. I know this had something to do with the .NET 1.1 to 2.0 change but we need to get this schema to work somehow.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Wow StackOverflow, where are your experts? 1 day, 12 views on the question and no attempt to a response!!!

I got help from a developer in the Philippines, they're definitely first class over there! Thanks Rose!

Here's her original message:

> Hello,
>
> Checking the schema from BizTalk 2004,
>   I see that schedulerepair element is
>   in xs:anyType with Derived By property
>   set to Extension. As far as I recall,
>   we cannot set the Derived By property
>   to Extension to derive from an
>   xs:anyType otherwise the error you
>   stated below will be encountered. To
>   correct this, we can either change the
>   Derived By property to Restriction or
>   change the Base Data Type property
>   from xs:anyType to some other types
>   and rebuild the schema.
>
> The error you encountered is raised
>   due to a new check which has been
>   introduced in the 2.0 framework as
>   part of the restructuring of the 2.0
>   XML libraries.
>
> Couldn’t exactly determine if that
>   really is the case here as I have no
>   Biztalk 2006 R2 to compile to but
>   anyway hope this helps. 
>
> Thanks! Rose

She didn't even have the newer Biztalk version to test it but her advice worked on my machine. Here's the new schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://Project.Schemas.External.ScheduleRepair" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="schedulerepair"> 
    <xs:complexType> 
      <xs:complexContent mixed="true"> 
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType"> 
          <xs:sequence>            
            <xs:element name="customerremarks"> 
              <xs:complexType /> 
            </xs:element> 
          </xs:sequence> 
        </xs:restriction> 
      </xs:complexContent> 
    </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

Amazing work Rose! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, there aren't too many BizTalk experts on this site, though to be fair there aren't too many BizTalk experts around period.